# Three.js cube is not rendering after bundling – Webpack, Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, three.js, bundle

I’m trying to integrate three.js with wordpress via webpack. The problem is that, 3d cube is not appearing inside canvas.

```
<div class="div" id="canvas"></div>
```

is empty.

If I would put app.js code into `<script>`, inside page.php, using CDN src, it works. (the way without bundling)

But I thought it will be nice to bundle it just as other scripts.

Source:

app.js:

```
import "./example.js";
```

example.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
$("#canvas").append( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );

cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

renderer.render( scene, camera );


};

animate();
```

page.php:

```
<?php

get_header();
?>


<main id="home-primary" class="site-main">
<div class="div" id="canvas"></div>


</main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

// change these variables to fit your project
const jsPath= './js';
const cssPath = './css';
const outputPath = 'dist';
const localDomain = 'http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio';
const entryPoints = {
  // 'app' is the output name, people commonly use 'bundle'
  // you can have more than 1 entry point
  'app': jsPath + '/app.js',
  'style': cssPath + '/main.scss',

};

module.exports = {
  entry: entryPoints,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputPath),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),

    // Uncomment this if you want to use CSS Live reload
    
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      proxy: localDomain,
      //files: [ outputPath + '/*.css' ]
      files: ['style.css', 'js/**/*.js', '**/*.php'],
      injectCss: true,
    }, { reload: false, }),
    
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?[c]ss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: { indentedSyntax: true }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/i,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=1024'
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^19.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
    "dir-archiver": "^1.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "rtlcss": "^3.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },


  "scripts": {
    "watch": "node-sass sass/ -o ./ --source-map true --output-style expanded --indent-type tab --indent-width 1 -w",
    "compile:css": "node-sass sass/ -o ./ && stylelint '*.css' --fix || true && stylelint '*.css' --fix",
    "compile:rtl": "rtlcss style.css style-rtl.css",
    "lint:scss": "wp-scripts lint-style 'sass/**/*.scss'",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js 'js/*.js'",
    "bundle": "dir-archiver --src . --dest ../_s.zip --exclude .DS_Store .stylelintrc.json .eslintrc .git .gitattributes .github .gitignore README.md composer.json composer.lock node_modules vendor package-lock.json package.json .travis.yml phpcs.xml.dist sass style.css.map yarn.lock",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.137.5"
  }
}
```

No console errors.

Comment: Where are you including the `app.js` build? In WordPress that is usually in the `function.php` file but are you doing it?

Comment: yes. I’ve enqueued app.js:  `wp_enqueue_script( 'jakubtrz-portfolio-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/app.js' );`

Comment: When you run Webpack, can you confirm that it produces a `app.js` file within a `dist` folder? If so, you might just need to adjust the path.

Comment: Webpack produced app.js.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with your code. A couple of things that I would check to debug this, it would be. 1) Check if the produced `app.js` has the content of the `three.js` library. 2) Check if the browser is returning a cached version of the `app.js` file. 3) Check the paths to be sure that you are importing the correct produced path. Let me know if any of those help.

Comment: 1) app.js contains three.module.js 2) it appears in the browser 3) paths are correct...

Comment: What I found in threejs docs is that: "Using three.js in Node.js can be difficult, for two reasons:

First, because three.js is built for the web, it depends on browser and DOM APIs that don't always exist in Node.js. [...]”

Comment: "Second, Node.js support for ES modules is ... complicated. As of Node.js v12, the core library can be imported as a CommonJS module, with require('three’)."

Comment: I’m very beginner, could this have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241773/discussion-between-david-fontes-and-guyfromtheinternet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you are including the script in the head tag, just move it to the end of the body (footer).

You are not able to see anything because your script tries to get the canvas element, which does not yet exist at that time. By moving your script to the end, you are ensuring that your page has rendered before your script is ran.

Using WordPress you can do:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jakubtrz-portfolio-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/app.js', array(), false, true );
```

The last argument is the one that indicate WordPress to add the script in the footer. By default, it is false hence, added in the head tag.